# CSS sprite position problem

Tags: css-sprites, background-position, css

I trying to create a fixed border to the site that dynamically change size with the browser window from this sprite (it isn't perfect I know.): http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/269/7/0/bordersprite_by_nakos-d4ayzne.png

[**DEMO on jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheNAkos/kJQAa/)

My problem as you can see is the vertical wall part. As the `#falJ` and `#falB` are `height:100%` they include the bottom wall's end too with the space between the two wall sprites. Is there a way to force `backround-position` to only use vertical wall part without bottom wall's end?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Short answer:* No, this is not the way to do what you want to do. You cannot accommodate fluidity with a sprite that doesn't meet the potential maximum size.

*Long answer:* I'll write up a solution for you in the morning if nobody has been able to assist you with it yet.

Comment: @vonkly I was afraid of this. It would be cool if you show me a way to do this. I can wait your solution then :) Thank you :)

Comment: Putting it together for you now - I'll edit this comment when it's complete. Quick question: Is the *width* of the element fixed, or did you need that to be fluid, too?

Comment: @vonkly the width of the left and the right walls are fixed, only the height changes as the window height changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>**Solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/Ld43B/</s>

It's not the prettiest thing in the world, but it achieves what you want. Check out the source code & direct link for the background images to see what you'll need to do. It's currently set at 299px wide; I imagine you'll be using something wider.

I'd also suggest adding some padding around your content (either with a p tag, span, another div, etc.) - the way it is currently set up isn't what I'd recommend for readability.

**EDIT**

The only way I can imagine achieving a fluid width + height box with the borders that you have in the way that you want is to use a second image for the west and east containing divs. This should work with your current method.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I want to achieve. We misunderstand each other. :) The point is I want it to fit in any screen size even when I re-size the window on the fly. In this the top and bottom will always fixed size.

Comment: You told me *"only the height changes as the window height changes";* this is not correctly describing your goal. To achieve what you want, use your previous method, and simply using a different image for the west and east walls. *There is no way to repeat a specific portion of an image (sprite) in the way you want*.

Comment: Yeah I see where my English led you the wrong way. I didn't find other solution anywhere else, so I do what you said just now. :) Thank you for your time. If you write this comment in answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Answer revised. Thanks! I'll keep this in the back of my mind and let you know if I think of something.